# Creating a newenvironment with an optional second argument

Tags: floats, environments, minipage

everyone.

I'm trying to create an environment that works like figure, but in a minipage environment.

This environment is going to receive the figure position arguments in addition of the minipage width as the second one. Here is my code:

```
\newenvironment{figuremp}[2][]
  {\@float{figure}\begin{center}\begin{minipage}{#2}\begin{center}}
  {\end{center}\end{minipage}\end{center}\end@float}
```

I want that, if the user type `\begin{figuremp}[!h]`, this environment set the minipage width as `\textwidth`. But it only works if I type `\begin{figure}[ht]{some width}`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should consider `\NewDocumentEnvironment` of `xparse` (now integrated in the kernel of LaTeX).

Comment: What would be the reason for the `minipage`? A `figure` is already a single block that cannot be split. If you center the body, the width of the inner minipage is irrelevant.

Comment: `\begin{center}` should normally be avoided in figures  (as vertical space is already added around the float) and use `\centering` instead which adds no vertical space, having two adjacent optional arguments doesn't usually work well as an interface as you can not omit the first argument if you need to use the second. You have two `center` so  you are adding two lots of spurious vertical space. as egreg says you can omit the minipage